# How to turn off Yahoo Mail notifications in 4.1.2.?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications, yahoo-mail

I just upgraded my Android OS to 4.1.2. and the Yahoo Mail is pushing audible notifications again (I had disabled them in the previous version of OS).  When I go into the app, there is no settings in the menu.  How do I disable the notifications?

Comment: Is it audio-only, or do some messages appear in the notification bar along with it?

Comment: both.  i want both turned off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When such a notification appears...

1. Open your notification area
2. Long-press on the notification. This opens the app's settings in the system configuration.
3. Here you can disable all notifications from the app.

This is a feature introduced with JellyBean -- as you've stated your device is running Android 4.1.2, this setting should be available to you.

Answer (score 2):

In the official [Yahoo! Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail) app, Yahoo recently changed the layout so that the Settings menu is no longer accessed by pressing the "Menu" button.

Launch the app and tap the little `<` arrow next to the "Inbox" label on the upper-left corner of the screen.  This will reveal the Folders menu.  Scroll it down to the "Tools" section, tap on `Settings`, then tap on `Account settings` option, and finally on `Notification Settings`.  From here you can set up the notification options for new messages:

- `Choose Sound` -> `No sound` -> `Done` to disable audible notifications,
- `Use Vibrate` to toggle vibration on and off,
- `Show in Status Bar` to toggle the icon in your Notification panel.

If there is no "Notification Settings" tap the text that lists your e-mail address associated with the account, and you will find the settings there to shut off notifications, both audible and visual.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Yahoo Mail app
2. Tap the 3 lines in the top left, or scroll right from the left edge of the screen. You'll see (from top to bottom): Inbox, Drafts, Starred, Outbox, etc
3. Scroll down to the 'Tools', then 'Mail settings'
4. Tap 'Mail notification settings', deselect 'Enable notifications' or 'Use vibrate' (this can be done at the same time for multiple accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Finally! after months of Googling and asking others with Androids (Samsung Galaxy 4) how to turn off the yahoo notifications and getting a failed result, I finally got it on my own! Okay, here it goes: I opened up the yahoo app, far left on the email bar next to inbox are three lines. Press the lines and this will open up to your folders. Scroll all the way down to the very end and select Settings. Scroll down to General and select Notifications. Your mail notifications will all be blue, switch them to off (grey shading). And there you go!

Answer (score 0):

2019 Updates: 
 - 'Setting' 
 - 'App & Notification' 
 - 'Yahoo Mail' 
 - 'Notification' 
 - Tap on the name of each type, such as 'Mail from people', 'Reminder' etc 
 - Under 'Behavior', select 'Show silently' 
 
You have to repeat the last two steps for each type.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove your yahoo account from your android phone. Just go to settings - > Account & Sync  - > Serlect Account and the you will find the option to delete the account.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to get rid of the entire account -- just the notifications should be turned off. See the question again and the comments to it.